# Creating a data structure with unknown size python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I want to create a data structure (not sure if it should be a list or a dictionary) but I don't know it's size in advance. How can I proceed to create this structure and add an unknown ammount of elements to it by input?

Comment: You don't need to specify size in Python at all. Please be more specific

Comment: Did you try anything? Like, just doing it and notice that it works out of the box?

Comment: Python is not C. You don't do this in basic Python. Sometimes it's useful in numpy, are you using that?

Comment: I may not need to specify size, but I need limits to the range function. Otherwise how can I keep adding elements if I don't know when to stop?

Comment: Basically, my program is to receive an unknown ammount of numbers, and I should write an algorithm to do a binary search among these numbers and verify whether or not a specific number is one of these numbers. I thought about using a list to store all these numbers and then iterate over it to search the particular number, but I'm not being able to store all the numbers in a list or dictionary. If anyone could give me a hand, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should post the program here with the exact problem

Comment: n=str(input().zfill(3)) #number to be searched
print("Elemento procurado: ", n)
vet=[]         #vector(list) of numbers
i=(input().zfill(3).split(","))
branco=''
def printvet(vet):
    k=0
    for k in range(len(vet)):
        print("+" + 5*"-" + "+", end=branco)
    print()
    for k in range(len(vet)):    
        print("| ", end=branco)
        print(vet[k] + '', end=branco)
for l in i:
    l=str(l).zfill(3)
    if l not in vet:
        vet.append(l.zfill(3))

Comment: I would like to add zeros to each element of the list 'vet' until all elements become three digit-numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list in python, you can use the `list.append(item)` method in order to insert new elements into it, you don't have to specify the size of the list in order to use it and it will grow as your append more items.

Comment: but how can I create a loop to add elements if I don't know how many elements I want to add?

Comment: Sounds like the prime example for a `while` loop to me

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a while loop to stop after some input. You can try this. It will break at enter key.

```
list = []
while True:
    x = input("Enter numbers:")
    if x =='':
        break
    else:
        list.append(int(x))
print(list)
```